# Data type inside swift protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

Let say I have the following protocol :

`protocol DataResponse { .... }`

My question is, how can I make another protocol like the following? :

`protocol AnotherProtocol { var data:[DataProtocol] { get } }`

When I am trying to do the above in my `Struct` below, I get `Type 'MyStruct' does not conform to protocol 'AnotherProtocol'`

```
struct myStruct : AnotherProtocol {

  var data:[a struct implements DataProtocol] ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to realize?

```
protocol DataResponse {
}

protocol AnotherProtocol {
    var data:[DataResponse] { get }
}

struct myStruct : AnotherProtocol {
    var data:[DataResponse]
}
```

This code compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in your answer is not very clear so I don't know what you are trying to do, but that should works for you:

```
protocol DataProtocol {
}

protocol AnotherProtocol {
    var data:[DataProtocol] { get }
}

struct dataStruct : DataProtocol {
}

struct myStruct : AnotherProtocol {

    var data:[DataProtocol] {
        return [dataStruct()]
    }
}
```

Comment: what I want to do is `struct myStruct : AnotherProtocol {
    
    var data:[dataStruct] {
        return [dataStruct()]
    }
}
` because I have a lot of structs implement `DataProtocol `